# Different definitions of suspension in a pointed model category

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a pointed model category (i.e.  $\mathcal{C}$ has the structure of a model category, and in the category  $\mathcal{C}$, the initial and terminal object $*$ are isomorphic).

I have encountered two definitions of the suspension of an object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$:

1. Via cylinder objects: We choose a factorization of the two-fold map $\nabla=(id_X,id_X) : X\amalg X\to X$ into a cofibration $(i_0,i_1)$ followed by an acyclic fibration $q$ (note that I am describing what is usually called a very good cylinder object):
   \begin{equation}X\amalg  X \stackrel{(i_0,i_1)}{\rightarrowtail}Cyl X\stackrel{q~\sim}{\twoheadrightarrow} X\end{equation}
   We define $\Sigma' X$  as the following pushout:

   [image: po diagram involving cylinder]
2. We define $\Sigma X$ as the homotopy pushout of

   [image: hty po diagram]

   The homotopy pushout can be calculated by choosing a cofibrant replacement $*\rightarrowtail QX\stackrel{\sim}{\twoheadrightarrow}X$, and then factorizing the map $QX\to *$ as $QX\stackrel{j}{\rightarrowtail} S\stackrel{\sim}{\twoheadrightarrow} *$ and considering the pushout:

   [image: po diagram for ht po]

My question is:
Are the two objects $\Sigma'X$ and $\Sigma X$ weakly equivalent in $\mathcal{C}$?
If not, are they equivalent if $X$ is already cofibrant?

The anser to the second question at least is true in $Top_*$, where we get the reduced suspension of a space in both cases.

Comment: The exact subtleties of model categories are eluding me right now, but I think the most general case these will be the same is when homotopy pushouts of cofibrant objects can be computed by replacing one of the maps with a cofibration. This happens in left proper model categories.

Answer (score 1):

At least when $X$ is cofibrant, they are weakly equivalent. This is because any cocartesian square in a model category consisting of cofibrant objects is  homotopy cocartesian if one of the leg of the underlying cospan is a cofibration. (See, e.g., Lurie's Higher Topos Theory, Proposition A.2.4.4).
To spell out the details, let $CX$ be the pushout of $\operatorname{Cyl}(X)\xleftarrow{i_1} X\to \ast.$ Since $\operatorname{Cyl}(X)\vee \operatorname{Cyl}(X)$ is a cylinder object of $X\vee X$, we have $CX\vee CX\cong C(X\vee X)$. Now $\Sigma 'X$ is the homotopy pushout of $\ast\leftarrow X\vee X\xrightarrow{\nabla} X$, which can be computed as the pushout $C(X\vee X)\leftarrow X\vee X\xrightarrow{\nabla} X$. Under the isomorphism $CX\vee CX\cong C(X\vee X)$, we can identify the latter pushout as $CX\vee _XCX=\Sigma X$.